# Прямая речь, косвенная речь и цитаты

Tags: общие-вопросы

Добрый день. У меня возник вопрос. Есть следующий текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я выделил слово "помощник" в прямой речи, если так называется программа? Это ее непосредственное название. Сленговое или реальное, не в этом суть.

И чем в данном случае является "помощник"? Цитатой? Названием?

Я совершенно запутался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот отрывок **семантически неясен, поэтому его трудно оформить.**  Воспринимается это примерно так. Антон придумал программу, но названия у нее ещё нет. Это название рождается непосредственно при разговоре, поэтому первое упоминание о программе может выглядеть примерно так: **Программа-помощник.**..

Далее Антон понимает, что программу можно назвать именно  "Помощником", и тогда название уже заключается в кавычки (это уже имя собственное). 
―"Помощник"... - вновь пробормотал он.

Но следует отметить, то глаголы "передернуло", "пробормотал" неудачно вписываются в текст.

1) **ПЕРЕДЁРНУТЬ**,   // кого. **Заставить содрогнуться, ужаснуться от испуга, отвращения и т.п.** П. при воспоминании об увиденном. Такой фильм кого хочешь передёрнет. □безл. От этой жути всех передёрнуло.

Как видно из словаря, этим глаголом описывается **негативное чувство**. Можно было бы остановиться на такой фразе: "И вдруг он запнулся на полуслове".

**ЗАПНУТЬСЯ**, 2. Оборвать или замедлить речь. З. на полуслове.

2) Если оставить "опять пробормотал", то получается, то раньше он тоже не говорил, а бормотал. Как вариант: ―"Помощник"... - вновь **повторил** он.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.
Что касается глаголов, то они подобраны корректно. Просто из-за ограниченности фрагмента не видно всей смысловой картины целиком.

Answer (score 0):

Первое употребление слова - название. Название новое, пробуемое на "вкус".

*(И вдруг его передёрнуло,* - зачем запятые? "Вдруг" не вводное.)

Второе появление в тексте "Помощника" может быть ***равно повтором названия и цитатой*** - этим самым пробованием на вкус: удачно-неудачно.

(Судя по передёргу - неудачно.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я не понял, что вы имеете в виду.